# Session Local Storage or Server side session at ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have list of Objects containing no sensitive data ( i.e. simple settings of a widget at client side 5-6 integer values and Guid, probably multiple widgets at the same time).

At the moment, I am using ASP.NET MVC Session. It doesn't seems to be relieable. It is getting null time to time for certain keys those are stored inside that. It happens when I launch application at debugging or Network is slow.

Can I use Client side session Storage for storing all settings? ( i.e. sessionStorage or localStorage ).

I am concerned about IIS re-cycling which causes session to remove
or any server side exception.

**Edit**

```
public ActionResult ApplySettingsForDashboard(DashboardCommonSettings settings)
{
  Session[string.Concat("SettingsToApply_",settingsToApply.PanelGuid)]=settings;
}

public DashboardCommonSettings GetSettingsFromSession(string PanelGuid)
{
    var settings = Session[string.Concat("SettingsToApply_",PanelGuid)]
}
```

Comments and suggetions are welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: Client side localStorage is saved until user clears history, it doesn't depend on any server side events. So you can use it. However, it only saves settings within one browser on one machine. So if the same user goes to the website from another place, these settings will be lost.

BTW, what's wrong with your regular session? Why do you think it's not reliable? If you get null from time to time it means you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
What should be used. I was in favor of using server side session. But as I described, during debugging or even running application without debugger in local environment,  session values gets removed against certain keys inside session. As a result I get null when i access Session[Guid+"name"]...

Comment: Sergey Benzenko :  Do you think usage of session is correct somehow .
I am editing the post. continue

Comment: 1) Try explicitly set the type of settings variable:
var settings = Session[string.Concat("SettingsToApply_",PanelGuid)] as DashboardCommonSettings;
2) Make sure you don't destroy the session somewhere (do logout or something).

Comment: no i am explicitly typecasting it. it was just a an idea how i am doing in code.
There is no logout during the current session. This happens, during the live session in the context of logged in user.
Dont know why.

Comment: @SergeyBenzenko regular ASP.Net session state is per browser's session also.

Comment: Whether to use localStorage or persistent ASP.Net session state is completely *opinion based* - you have to make your own decision. Obviously you should not be using in-memory session state for any serious purposes so most of the complains in the post related to just development environment and such behavior is totally expected.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : Could be ..because it creates identifier for the corresponding logged in user  and send it to clientside for storing in cookie.
So next time same user sends request , this cookie will be used and server will identify browser sent cookie and verify the user.
If user goes another machine, same cookie wont be available there too.
Make sense?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : so, on getting values from session wont hurt? session values will never get lost in un expected way the way they are getting lost in development environment? Because I observed this behavior only in dev  env. On production server is little fast, didn't see this behavior there.

Comment: Yes, default ASP.Net session state uses cookies to identify session and one would need to make special effort to share it between different browsers sessions. You can use persistent session state on your development machine too... and if your production machines use in-memory session state you'll see same issues as you see on your dev machine, just a bit less frequently.

Comment: persistent session state = database you mean?
Then In-Memory Session State should never be used? Because its not reliable? . It would make sense to use then Local Storage at client side.?
One Important Q : Why User then don't get log out un expectedly? where same user's session keys gets null time to time.

Comment: @Usman - See [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). In process session state is almost completely useless in production applications because IIS app pool restarts will reset it every time. Authentication and session state are 2 different things that are completely separate from one another, the former only relies on a cookie, the latter on a (different) cookie and a server-side [session state provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of comments, I want to answer in a way : Use Out-Proc Session storage ( persistent storage ) for reliable session storage as much as possible. It would be slow, so need to be used cautiously. In-Proc session storage is highly unreliable specifically at production environment. Either localStorage ( client side ) can be taken as an option when we don't have sensitive data.

Other answers are also welcome.